# Finding element tag name for search results of a webpage in a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, xml, webbrowser-control, html, htmlcollection

I am opening this url in webbrowser control
http://www.simplyrecipes.com/?s=chicken
 and i want to show only search results in the webbrowser control (the middle section of site containing different chicken recipes option) . I am not able to find out the specific element tag for the same. Please guide. if there is any other approach to achieve the task( showing only search result part of webpage,please suggest.
Thanks